# Custom Spring bean tag with child property tag

Tags: spring

I have a custom tag I have created for Spring using the AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.  For this tag I want to use a  tag as a child tag, but I don't want to have to implement the XML Element parsing by hand.

Can someone tell me where is the code that Spring uses to parse the <property> tag?  That, or how to leverage existing code to parse it for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "XML Element parsing"? You mean extracting stuff from the `Element` object supplied by `ParserContext`?

Comment: Using the AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser you are handed an Element object in doParse and I'm currently traversing that to derive the configuration

Comment: That's how the internal Spring classes do it. You'll just have to stick with that, I think.

Comment: Any idea which class that is in so I can use it as a base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using one of the existing subclasses of `AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser` as a template, and producing your own version. To pick a random example that uses nested elements - `ScheduledTasksBeanDefinitionParser`. This demonstrates how to chunk through the supplied `Element` object represnting your tag, and how to convert nested elements into useful config.